# Rxjs `shareReplay` 6.5.4 with angular 9x not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my service, I have integrated the sharereplay from RXJS. but navigating between pages, share replay not considered. each time my api updated from remote. any one help me to understand the issue? show me the correct way to implement the same?

service code:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface PostProps {
    userId: number;
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    processed: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class PersonnelDataService {
    list$: Observable<PostProps[]>;

    private URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    fetchPersonnelList() {
        if (!this.list$) {
            this.list$ = this.http.get<PostProps[]>(this.URL).pipe( 
                map((response: PostProps[]) => response),
                shareReplay(1),//not works
                catchError(async (error) => this.handleError(error))
            );
        }
        return this.list$;
    }

    handleError(error) {
        throwError(error);
    }
}
```

component:

```
ngOninit(){
   this.personalDataService.fetchPersonneList();
   this.personnelList$ = this.personnelDataService.list$
}
```

**I updated the code like this:**

```
this.list$ = this.http.get<PostProps[]>(this.URL).pipe( shareReplay(1));
```

I am getting data. but still when I navigate to child page, getting new api call.?!

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-ajnttn?file=src/app/postService.ts)

Comment: where did you subscribe ?

Comment: A few comments: 1. your map is not needed, since you map the emitted value to itself. 2. The anonymous function passed to catchError doesn't have to be an async function. 3. throwError(error) is deprecated. You should pass a function to it. 4. the catchError block is not needed when you just rethrow the error. 5. In your case you could just define `list$` directly as defined in `fetchPersonnelList`. You don't need the function call at all. The HTTP request will be triggered the first time someone subscribes to this observable. Maybe remove the catchError block and see if it works.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka see me component code : `this.personnelList$`

Comment: @FabianStrathaus - in map I am adding extra property. so I use it. removed the catch block, still the same result

Comment: @FabianStrathaus - can you check my update?

Comment: Actually I have the presumption that your problem is somewhere else. Are you 100% sure that you only have 1 instance of `PersonnelDataService`? Where exactly in your modules do you import (add to your providers array) the service? Do you maybe have two places? If yes, you can try to add `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` to your service and remove it from all modules.

Comment: Live Domo yelds errors and do not boot

Comment: Please check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-ajnttn?file=src%2Fapp%2FpostService.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html additionally getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.http.get')` error too

Comment: still the same ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at <instance_members_initializer> (postService.ts:22:24)

Comment: @FabianStrathaus - I did not provide the `root`, because I decided to destroy the service when component killed

Comment: Live demo does not work. Anyway - if used correctly shareReply will work as intended ergo you are not using it correctly

Comment: Well, wenn you destroy the service once the component gets killed (e.g. when during routing), then this could be the reason that your service is reinstantiated and the `list$` is newly created as well.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus - but I am visiting the child page. not outside of the module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can finally be seen in your CodeSandbox example. your problem is not, that `shareReplay` is not working.

You actual problem is that in your component, you add the following: `providers: [PostService]`. Basically you are telling Angular to instantiate a new service each time the component is constructed. Once you navigate to another route (which is not a child route as you stated) the component is destroyed and reinstantiated once you click the back button. Therefore you have two different services with different observables. This will lead to a retriggering of the HTTP call.

Once I remove the providers array from component level and either

1. define the service to be available at root level like

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PostService {
```

2. or add the service to the providers array of your module

The second call is gone. The reason is that only one instance of the service will be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works.

By assigning a new value to your variable, you're disconnecting your components from listening to the observable, and you create potential memory leaks.

Use subjects instead.

```js
private _list = new BehaviorSubject<PostProps[]>([]);
public list$ = this._list.asObservable();

// ...

fetchPersonnelList() {
  return this.http.get<PostProps[]>(this.URL).pipe( 
    tap(list => this._list.next(list)),
    catchError(async (error) => this.handleError(error)),
  );
}
```

Comment: Note that you will have to call `this.myService.fetchPersonnelList().subscribe()` everytime for it to work. Without the subscribe, nothing will happen.

Comment: But when I navigate to child page and back to parent, parent again getting data from api. but it's not taking from BheaviorSubject. which is not good right?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hopper-rqrq5x - live demo. click the link and back button to list page. fetching the data as new request